# ¿Debería poder permitirse algún tipo de pregunta de opinión?

Tags: discusión

Navegando por distintos sitios de Stack Exchange, a pesar de que tenía entendido que los sitios suelen ser de preguntas y respuestas concretas, sin dar lugar a posibles debates, existen sitios como [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) y similares en los que prácticamente ninguna pregunta tiene respuesta única, sino que estas dependen en gran medida de la subjetividad. Sé que cada sitio tiene sus normas, pero dado que las preguntas subjetivas se permiten en algunos sitios, me preguntaba si no habría algún tipo de pregunta subjetiva que se pudiera llegar a permitir aquí.

Sé que me he perdido muchos años de debate en Spanish Language, y desde luego las características del sitio dan pie a que las preguntas sean más del tipo preguntas concretas con respuestas objetivas. Yo reconozco que algunas veces he bordeado la subjetividad con preguntas como [esta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18511/12637). Sin embargo, aun así me estaba preguntando si no habría algún tipo de pregunta subjetiva que se pudiera considerar válida, dado que a veces el propio idioma puede dar lugar a interpretaciones. No se me ocurre ahora mismo ningún caso, pero si alguien tiene alguna aportación, ¿se podría aportar como respuesta, y examinar detenidamente los casos más votados? ¿O se han excluido ya totalmente del sitio?

Comment: Interesante lectura en la sección del help center [Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive](/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 3):

Yo creo que no.

Por un lado, quiero recalcar que en este sitio estamos demasiado empeñados en que la mayoría de nuestras preguntas se responden o se pueden responder con una sola respuesta. O que no hay necesidad de otras respuestas dada una primera respuesta medianamente correcta. Es decir, que si alguien explica algo y lo explica medianamente bien no tiene mucho sentido poner otra respuesta.

En los *stack* de programación, en cambio, un problema se podría resolver de varias maneras, y ahí entra el tema de los **votos**, para que la comunidad haga "flotar" o sobresalir la mejor respuesta (elegante, simple, eficiente, fácil de entender o implementar...). En otros, como el de Ciencia ficción, la gente pone respuesta muy parecidas (hay también muchísima actividad y "competencia", por lo que para cuando alguien ha terminado de escribir su respuesta otro usuario acaba justo de publicar la suya, dejando la del otro potencialmente "obsoleta" o como un mero plagio...) y a veces se distinguen solo por la calidad de las referencias, explicación o formato.

Creo que muchas de nuestras respuestas, aunque no estén basadas en opinión, pueden tener una componente subjetiva importante, y encima tenemos diferencias regionales. Resumiendo, a veces la mejor respuesta es la que mejor resuelve tu problema (como es el caso que planteas en *parenting stack*, donde desde luego no hay soluciones como en el stack de programación) o la que mejor explica tu duda (si alguien pone una respuesta correcta, pero es difícil de entender, no veo por qué no podría alguien publicar la suya, explicando **lo mismo pero mejor**).

Dicho todo eso, creo que **no debería haber preguntas subjetivas**. El motivo es que creo que las respuestas dadas a una pregunta deberían servir para resolver una duda práctica. Por ejemplo, yo podría preguntar: "¿Creéis que la RAE debería admitir "[bolobonchi](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10405/5481)?" Pero las respuestas no nos van a llevar a ningún sitio. Pura opinión (salvo que tu objetivo fuese sondear al personal de este foro). Por el contrario si pregunto algo más objetivo como [qué haría falta para que la RAE admitiese esa palabra](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18511/5481) entonces tengo una respuesta a una duda práctica, y validación de la comunidad de su eficacia, que puedo aplicar a algo.

Por otro lado, [algunas de nuestras preguntas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19143/5481) pueden tener ya un cierto grado de subjetividad en la respuesta.

En cualquier caso, he visto [saltarse las reglas un par de veces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184618/3961519), usando las *community wiki answers*. Esto puede ser divertido, e interesante, pero no va a resolver ninguna duda práctica.

Es interante que la sección META funciona de forma diferente, y hay sitio para la opinión y para ofrecer ideas, mientras que la sección normal es "todo *business*.

Comment: Otra muesta de lo que digo, en [esta pregunta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19161/5481) ya hay quien **opina** que en la tradución podríamos prescidir de un término y para quien es relativamente importante. De momento nadie se atreve con una respuesta, quizá porque ven la pregunta como muy obvia, pero creo que esta pregunta podría dar lugar a un montón de aportaciones y opiniones distintas, y la comunidad ya hará sobresalir mediante votos las más interesantes.

Comment: Es interesante ver la evolución de [so]. Ha habido casos en los que las reglas se han saltado a la torera, o las propias preguntas han generado nuevas reglas. Al parecer, al principio se aceptaba casi de todo para conseguir que el sitio creciera; con el tiempo se fueron poniendo filtros para conseguir calidad. Es difícil ver en qué punto estamos en [spanish.se], pues carecemos de preguntas y de usuarios. Y lo mismo con las respuestas: muchas son más un comentario que otra cosa, pero que nos resistimos a eliminar con la [sana] intención de que su autor aprenda a manejarse en el sitio.